# Incorrect Duplicate insert problem with SQL Server CE 3.5

Tags: winforms, linq, sql-server-ce

I am not able to insert data into my table anymore!
Here's my table design.
[image]

intId is the Primary Key, there's no explicit unique constraint defined on it, has identity increment set to 1 and identity seed to 1.

I am inserting data into this table thru LINQ.

```
testDB.tbl_Vehicle.InsertOnSubmit(newVehicle);
testDB.SubmitChanges();
```

All this used to work till now, and all of a sudden it stopped working!
It now says

```
A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = tbl_Vehicle,Constraint name = PK_tbl_Vehicle ]
```

More info: This desktop application has 1 executable and 1 .sdf file. It was developed on Win 7 and recently was moved to Win XP system. But that shouldn't be a problem as there are other tables I am inserting into with similar logic and table design.

Comment: This one worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284045/a-duplicate-value-cannot-be-inserted-into-a-unique-index

Comment: @@Reddy S R - i already wrote in answer that you need to reset the identity column value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thin make use of SQL profiler and check the query fire on insert statement.

**More on check the database Table again and if possbile set the seed for the primary i.e identity column.**

Comment: Can we run Profiler on CE? Seed is set on intId column and that is my Primary key.

Comment: @Reddy S R - check the query generated by the contex class because i think profiler is not available for compact version