# A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a Unique index (but...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to add a product to the Cart, but it returns the following:

An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

> Inner exception: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005):
>   A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name
>   = Cart,Constraint name = PK_*Cart*_0000000000000997 ] at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr&
>   pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>
> Stack trace at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   entityCache) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges() at
>   JTS.Security.Identity.Push.ToCart(Int32 userId, String partNumber,
>   String productDescription, Int32 quantity, Decimal price, Decimal
>   lineTotal, String orderId, DateTime dateTime, Boolean isBoxed) in
>   c:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\WebSites\One\App_Code\JTS.cs:line 251

The thing is though, I don't have any Unique indexes. And I even tried removing all primary keys (just to see if that would change anything) - which it didn't.

The code:

```
public bool ToCart(int userId,
                    string partNumber,
                    string productDescription,
                    int quantity,
                    decimal price,
                    decimal lineTotal,
                    string orderId,
                    DateTime dateTime,
                    bool isBoxed)
                {
                    bool addedToCart = false;

                    try
                    {
                        Cart cart = new Cart()
                        {
                            UserId = userId,
                            PartNumber = partNumber,
                            Description = productDescription,
                            Quantity = quantity,
                            Price = price,
                            LineTotal = lineTotal,
                            OrderId = orderId,
                            OrderDate = dateTime,
                            IsBoxed = isBoxed
                        };

                        database.AddToCarts(cart);
                        database.SaveChanges();

                        addedToCart = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        addedToCart = false;
                        //Response(exception.Message);
                        addToCartExceptionDetails = exception.Message +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Inner exception" +
                            exception.InnerException +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Stack trace" +
                            exception.StackTrace;
                    }

                    return addedToCart;
                }
```

Also, if I create a new Order (which creates a new OrderID), it WILL add one item to the cart. BUT, It will never add anymore than 1 item to the cart under an existing OrderId!

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't this working?

Table Definition

---

```
Column Name   Data Type   Length   Allow Nulls     Unique    Primary Key
UserId        int         4        Yes             No        No
OrderId       nvarchar    1000     No              No        Yes
```

Comment: Please add your tables structure

Comment: I just did, though new users can't add images, so I'm typing it all in a separate tab.

Comment: If OrderId is the PK, how do you plan to insert more than one product to the cart?

Comment: If you've got a problem with a question, the least you could do is explain why, otherwise you'll always have problems with questions that - in your opinion - have problems.

Comment: I changed it so it wasn't primary key - but it still gives the same error. And I've since (like I said in my question) removed all primary keys - and I still receive the same error

Comment: the error code tells you which unique contraint you are violating: `Table name = Cart Constraint name = PK__Cart__0000000000000997 `

Comment: I seriously doubt you sucessfully removed the PK and all unique constraints and still got that error.  If the error references a SQL table constraint then that table has that constraint.

Comment: The table does not have the Constraint. I'm beginning to think that this is a VS or EF bug, where it does not update the underlying code; problem is - I can't remember where the underlying code is.

Comment: If the error code says you're violating a unique constraint, and tells you what table and what constraint, your conclusion is that it's a VS or EF bug?

Comment: Because I am using VS 2012 RC on Windows 8 release PREVIEW- it's _definitely going to have bugs_, and I've already run into 2 known bugs with EF and 4 with VS.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I've managed to solve/overcome this issue, by `deleting databasename.edmx from the App_Code folder, and removing relevant entries from Web.config file; then Adding Entity Model all over again.` I have no idea what caused the issue, but I have a feeling that when a column in the db was changed, it didn't update it somewhere else, and deleting/re-adding everything again forced the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table where you deleted and re-added content, you can get this error while inserting new rows with an ID equal to existing IDs
why dont you check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284045/a-duplicate-value-cannot-be-inserted-into-a-unique-index) form more info